# Update array object by specific index

Tags: reactjs

How can I update `groceries` item(set `completed` to `True`) in my `toggleGroceryCompleteness` method?

I tried `this.setState({groceries[groceryIndex]:{completed:true});`

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      groceries: [
        {
          name: "Apples",
          completed: false
        }
      ],
      newGroceryName: ""
    };

  toggleGroceryCompleteness(groceryIndex) {
    console.log(groceryIndex);
    console.log(this.state.groceries[groceryIndex]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're editing the value of a previously set state, you should use this definition of `setState`

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    const newGroceries = prevState.groceries.slice()
    newGroceries[groceryIndex].completed = true

    return { ...prevState, groceries: newGroceries }
})
```

This takes the value of the `groceries` state array from before the `setState` call and assigns it to a new variable to be modified, accessing the given index and sets the `completed` property to `true`. Then returns a new object/state containing everything from the previous state value but a modified `groceries` property which is the new modified version.

Comment: Two problems here: 1. `newGroceries` is a global variable—did you forget `const =`?; 2. This modifies the state directly. You probably meant to make a copies of the `groceries` array before modifying it: `const newGroceries = prevState.groceries.slice();`.

Comment: @JordanRunning yep! thanks for pointing that out! been writing too much python recently

Comment: @m_callens thanks! btw. why did you put `props` as argument in this arrow function?

Comment: @DemoDjango the `props` of the component is the second argument passed to this extended definition of `setState`. Whether you need it or not is up to you obviously but its there if you want it